# How do I stop my external monitor from occasionally blacking out?

Tags: mac, display, resolution

I have a 2011 MBP which is connected to a 1920x1080, 144 Hz monitor.  I am using one of these cables to connect it: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00YOQYQWY/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YOQYQWY)

On occasion the display will go black for a few seconds before turning back on.  It's not actually disconnecting since I would get a notification on my laptop screen of that event.  Sometimes I even hear a click noise when this happens.

It only happens when the resolution is set to 1080, even if I lower the refresh rate.  At lower resolutions it never happens.  If I use the DisableMonitor app to turn off my laptop's main screen my external display will still sometimes black out.  It seems to occur regardless of activity, as I can leave it idling with nothing on the screen or I can be playing an intensive game and it won't happen any more or less frequently.  This happens on Windows as well.

Anyone know the cause of this?

Comment: Have you tried using a different cable or connecting the same cable to a different monitor?

Comment: I don't have another cable or monitor to test it with.  I did order another cable from a different company (should arrive tomorrow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may encounter this issue, it was simply a monitor with defective timing.  I sent it in for a replacement which doesn't exhibit this problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Does it sometimes go completely black and you can not seem to get it turned on again?
- Does the monitor have its own menu button on the monitor itself to change monitor settings?

I aks because sometimes the monitor has its own sleep mode independent from the operating system.

Check the monitor-menu and check what settings are there and try find a manual - either online or the one made out of paper that came with your monitor.

Comment: The screen only goes out for a few seconds at most.  It always comes back.  I don't believe it has a sleep mode.  It has its own settings but I have DDC/CI turned on.